# Angular change route params without changing children route

Tags: angular

Here is a router configuration :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'atc/:atcId',
    component: AtcComponent,
    resolve: {
      atcList: 'atcList',
    },
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'goal', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'goal',
        component: GoalComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'visit',
        component: VisitComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to navigate to a "brother" page. So if i'm in /atc/1/goal, it want to go to /atc/2/goal. If i'm in /atc/1/visit, I want to go to /atc/2/visit.

Let's suppose my current route is /atc/1/visit
I want to navigate to atc of id 2.

I'm inside AtcComponent. For this parent component POV, my current route is /atc/1. It know nothing of 'goal' or 'visit'.
I do something like this :

```
this.router.navigate(['../', '2'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

But when I do this, it resolve it as /atc/2. It remove the 'visit' or 'goal' part. It is then redirected to /atc/2/goal because of route.

Did I miss something in the API or is there a way not too hacky to keep children route as it is ?

Thank you

Edit : Here is a stackblitz to better explain this case : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keep-children-route

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect in this way:

```
this.router.navigate(['../', '2', 'visit'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

Comment: Simplest answer yes, but I can't put 'visit' statically because I don't know if i'm in /atc/X/visit or /atc/X/goal from AtcComponent point of view.
I'll edit my question

Comment: Try this: this.router.navigate(['../', '2', this.activatedRoute.url[2].path], {relativeTo: this.route}); Im not sure the index of url you can try another

Comment: Check please, what is in this.activatedRoute.url[2].path variable, maybe index is wrong, im not sure.

Comment: I checked in debug, it does not exist

Comment: To be sure, you inject inside constructor 'private activatedRouter: ActivatedRouter' ?

Comment: Do you invoke your 'this.router.navigate..' when user clicks on item in AtcComponent or when ?

Comment: activatedRouter does not exist. I use activatedRoute.snapshot.url

Comment: I invoke navigate when user click on item yes. I could parse string in this.router.url but it seems kinda wrong to me. I'll build an online sample and  ask on angular github

Comment: So when you click on item you should pass clicked item to the onClick method and inside this method create navigation route like this: this.route.navigate(['../', item.id, item.type])

Comment: It is not like this, but I have just done a stackblitz to better explain this case : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keep-children-route

Comment: Take look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keep-children-route-yunfp2